# Обработка данных из csv

Tags: python, csv

всем привет.
Прошу помощи.
есть csv файл в таком виде, привожу неполный список

```
Questions,Answers,Directions
Курьер поздоровался с вами?,да;нет,2;2
Как и во что был одет курьер?,да;нет,3;3
Курьер соблюдает субординацию?,да;нет,4;4
Курьер проявляет индивидуальный подход?,да;нет,5;5
Курьер поблагодарил за заказ и попрощался с вами?,да;нет,6;6
Заказ доставлен своевременно?,да;нет,7;7
"Курьер предупредил вас заранее о том, что подъезжает (звонок/sms)?",да;нет,8;8
```

В котором цифры указывают на связь с др вопросами по индексу (далее в файле есть такие)

Мне нужно обрабатывать файл таким образом, чтобы
0. Завести список, куда будет записываться имя(кот надо спросить), вопрос и ответ(из csv)

1. Предлагать вопрос и варианты ответа
2. Проверять ответы на наличие подобных, если нет, то попросить еще раз ввести
3. Записывать в список [имя, вопрос ответ]
4. Если есть связь по индексу, задать еще  вопрос и записать, естественно
5. Полученный список записать в др csv файл.

Реализация.
Функция чтения файла и записи - просто реализуется, это понятно.
Не понятно, как мне этот файл обработать, чтобы подавать и вопросы и варианты ответов. Это первое. Второе как создать связь и прочитать ее, исходя из индексов.

есть такой код

```
def ask_question(question, answers):
print(f'Вопрос: {question}')
print('Введите вариант ответа:')
for i, ans in enumerate(answers, 1):
    print(f'{i}) {ans}')
return int(input()) - 1


def questions_processing(file):
"""Обработка вопросов из csv."""
    i = 0
    while True:
        questions = csv_reader(file)
        line = questions[i]
        question, answers, go_to = line.split(',')
        num_answer = ask_question(question, answers.split(';'))
        i = int(go_to.split(';')[num_answer]) - 1
```

Проблема в том, что если есть данные в кавычках, то ошибка, и если заканчивается файл, то ошибка, так же нет проверки валидации ответа. Потому что не понимаю как реализовать.

Comment: За вас всё вообще нужно написать? )  А какая ошибка если кавычки? split от кавычек никак не зависит же

Comment: ошибка такая если кавычки ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3). Можно не писать ничего, можно описать словами каким образом реализовать, потому что мне это неясно. проблема в том, что в кавычках, есть запятая, что рушит идея распаковки

Comment: CSV файл нужно парсить правильным инструментом - модулем “csv” или “pandas”, а не разбивать строки ручками по разделителю

Comment: окей, а что меняет, получаю я свой список, проблема разбиения его на вопросы, ответы и индексы остается           with open('qs.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    questions = []
    for row in reader:
        questions.append(','.join(row))
questions = questions[1:]

Comment: Проблема с парсингом "закавыченного" текста, который может содержать символ разделителя, легко решается при помощи правильного использования `csv` модуля. То что вы дальше "ломаете" CSV - `','.join(row)` - это уже другая проблема

Comment: Сформулируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы он был сфокусирован на __одной__ проблеме. На вопрос как правильно парсить CSV я вам уже ответил в комментариях. [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, только увидел, а где можно посмотреть, почитать про это?

Answer (score 1):

По сути, уважаемый **MaxU** вам уже ответил "парсить правильным инструментом". Если бы вы дали себе труд не оспаривать, а хотя-бы ознакомиться с тем, что он рекомендует, то поняли бы, что данные инструменты позволяют парсить данные не непонятно куда, а например в DataFrame, который может сильно упростить вам жизнь, взяв на себя работу с индексами. В том числе при импорте-экспорте данных в файл. И именно эти индексы можно использовать в качестве указателей на связь между вопросами.
Это есть ответ на вопрос - "как создать связь и прочитать ее, исходя из индексов".

Эта фраза " Не понятно, как мне этот файл обработать, чтобы подавать и вопросы и варианты ответов." -  осталась непонятна. Куда надо "подавать" вопросы и ответы?

Comment: я не оспаривал, уточнил свое понимание, мне сказали правильное использование - что это такое и где смотреть, не подсказали. ценность совета небольшая.